Jenkins Ambiguous Permission notification after upgrading the jenkins to latest version
before i was using jenkins in centos7 and the jenkins version is 2.173 now i migrated to debian12 and updated the jenkins to 2.440.3 i have copied the jenkins home directory to new server after migrating i have updated all the plugins to latest now after logging in i am getting an error like this
enter image description here
After updating Jenkins, it is sending a warning for ambiguous permission for project base permission.
Warning Messages as follows :-
Some permission assignments are ambiguous. It is recommended to update affected configurations to be unambiguous. See this overview page for a list of affected configurations.

This table contains rows with ambiguous entries. This means that they apply to both users and groups of the specified name. If the current security realm does not distinguish between user names and group names unambiguously, and if users can either choose their own user name or create new groups, this configuration may allow them to obtain greater permissions. It is recommended that all ambiguous entries are replaced with ones that are either explicitly a user or group.

how can i solve this please explain in brief i have folloed the stack solution of this Jenkins Ambiguous Permission
i followed the below mentioned solution but it didn't worked for me i was getting an error like  access denied this user is missing the overall read and write permission
You may fix it in config.xml files directly using GNU sed/find. Go to $JENKINS_HOME (usually /var/lib/jenkins) and run this command:
find config.xml jobs/ -name config.xml -exec sed -i '/USER:|GROUP:/! s//USER:/' '{}' ;
It will change the global config first (the global permissions) and then each of your jobs' config files, making each permission the USER type (if it isn't already typed). Then go to the Manage Jenkins menu and hit the "Reload Configuration from Disk" button (or just stop the jenkins service before running find/sed).
please help me solve this issue
i need detailed explaination and solution for my error.
